# Negative resistance in Thevenin equivalent using elementary devices?

Tags: resistors, thevenin, network

Is it possible to generate a negative resistance Thevenin equivalent using just resistances, ideal voltage sources, ideal current sources? I need a negative slope straight line I with respect to V. Ideal Diodes may be used as well.

Comment: Just resistances No. A reasonably straight slope can be adjusted for with a "Lambda diode" circuit. Load line example http://electronbunker.ca/NegativeResistance.html Google Images will have many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only generate negative resistance by using active devices and here is such example 
.The courtesy of this circuit goes to user Spehro Pefhany

[Circuit Simulation Link](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/wk9as8/editor_embed-circuit-stackexchange-2015-07-24/)

[image]